# ESRI Hive ST_Contains does not work properly

Tags: hadoop, sdk, hive, spatial, esri

Trying this with the JARs I could find (not sure they are the best choice for this, I needed to use ESRI and do it in Hive):

```
ADD JAR /home/user/lib/esri-geometry-api-1.2.1.jar;
ADD JAR /home/user/lib/spatial-sdk-hive-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
ADD JAR /home/user/lib/esri-geometry-api.jar;
ADD JAR /home/user/lib/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar;

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Polygon AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Polygon';
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Point AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Point';
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Contains AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Contains';
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Geometry AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Geometry';
```

Running the following query:

```
SELECT 
    IF(1=1, 40.7484445, 0) AS latitude, 
    IF(1=1,-73.9878531, 0) AS longitude 
FROM any_table 
WHERE 
    NOT ST_Contains(
        ST_POLYGON('POLYGON((170.0 20.0, -170.0 73.0, -50.0 20.0, -50.0 73.0))'), 
        ST_Point(CAST(longitude AS DOUBLE), CAST(latitude AS DOUBLE))) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Where polygon `'POLYGON((170.0 20.0, -170.0 73.0, -50.0 20.0, -50.0 73.0))'` is a roughly USA box, given coordinates `40.7484445,-73.9878531` belong to New York. The result is supposed to be empty with WHERE NOT, but it still returns these coordinates. It does not filter as it supposed to.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing I notice is duplicate jars - two copies of the Geometry API, and spatial-sdk-hive contains most of spatial-sdk-hadoop .

Comment: If I only use these jars, still the same problem: ADD JAR /home/user/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/esri-geometry-api.jar;
ADD JAR /home/user/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar;

Comment: This returns NULL: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((170.0 20.0, -170.0 73.0, -50.0 20.0, -50.0 73.0))'))) AS usa FROM any_table LIMIT 1;

Comment: ST_AsText(ST_AsBinary(...)) does not look right; try ST_AsText(ST_GeomFrom...))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one version of the geometry API should be loaded.  Likewise only one of either spatial-sdk-hadoop or the pair of spatial-sdk-json and spatial-sdk-hive .

WKT polygons are closed with an end vertex that repeats the start vertex.

The polygon needs to be specified by vertices in order around the perimeter, not a zigzag order.

The Geometry API is planar and will not support wrapping around the antimeridian.

Probably -170 rather than +170 latitude is intended.

wget https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/releases/download/v1.1/spatial-sdk-hive-1.1.jar  \ 
https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/releases/download/v1.1/spatial-sdk-json-1.1.jar  \ 
https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/releases/download/v1.2.1/esri-geometry-api-1.2.1.jar

hive -S 
add jar /pathto/esri-geometry-api-1.2.1.jar 
/pathto/spatial-sdk-json-1.1.jar 
/pathto/spatial-sdk-hive-1.1.jar ; 
create temporary function ST_AsBinary as 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_AsBinary'; 
-- ...

select ST_Contains(ST_Polygon(1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1), ST_Point(2, 3)); 
true 
select ST_Contains(ST_Polygon('POLYGON((1 1, 1 4, 4 4, 4 1, 1 1))'), ST_Point(2, 3)); 
true 
select ST_Contains(ST_POLYGON('POLYGON((-170.0 20.0, -170.0 73.0, -50.0 20.0, -50.0 73.0, -170.0 20.0))'), ST_Point(-73.9878531, 40.7484445)); 
true 
select not ST_Contains(ST_POLYGON('POLYGON((-170.0 20.0, -170.0 73.0, -50.0 20.0, -50.0 73.0, -170.0 20.0))'), ST_Point(-73.9878531, 40.7484445)); 
false

Comment: Thank you! I corrected 170.0 to -170.0 like you suggested and used the same jar files. With the point given in the example it works, but with this one in Georgia - it does not. SELECT ST_Contains(ST_Polygon('POLYGON((-170.0 20.0, -170.0 73.0, -50.0 20.0, -50.0 73.0, -170.0 20.0))'), ST_Point(-83.919693, 30.88512));

Comment: Now as I corrected the order of points in the polygon switching the first two points, it works: SELECT ST_Contains(ST_Polygon('POLYGON((-170.0 73.0, -170.0 20.0, -50.0 20.0, -50.0 73.0))'), ST_Point(-83.919693, 30.88512)); true

Answer (score 0):

```
add jar /home/..../esri-geometry-api-1.2.1.jar;
add jar /home/..../spatial-sdk-json-1.2.0.jar;
add jar /home/..../spatial-sdk-hive-1.2.0.jar;
add jar /home/..../spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar;

create temporary function ST_AsBinary as 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_AsBinary';

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Polygon AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Polygon';

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Point AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Point';

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Contains AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Contains';

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Geometry AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Geometry';

A) load table from geojson data to hive:

CREATE TABLE default.lim_xxx_pais
(
NOM_PLAN string,
 NMO_PLAN  string,
 APROXIMADO string,
 ID1 string,
 BoundaryShape binary
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.GeoJsonSerDe'              
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.EnclosedGeoJsonInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';

B)

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/.../lim_xxx_pais.geojson' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE lim_xxx_pais
```

;

```
C)

select NOM_PLAN, NMO_PLAN,APROXIMADO,ID1 from default.lim_centrales_pais aa
where ST_Contains(aa.boundaryshape, ST_POINT(-72.08726603,-36.62627804) )
;
```

Comment: No explanation with only code is highly discouraged. Though it might solve the problem you should be able to tell why it solved the problem.

Comment: Only one of either spatial-sdk-hadoop or the pair of spatial-sdk-json and spatial-sdk-hive, should be loaded.